# How to separate approvals of multiple jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline that consists of two jobs, for QA and Production. Each job has a corresponding environment:

```
jobs:
- deployment: QA
  displayName: QA Deployment
  environment: QA
...
- deployment: Production
  dependsOn: QA
  displayName: Production Deployment
  environment: Production
...
```

And each environment is set to request an approval:

[image]

I expected to have a separate approval for each job, i.e. to be able to approve the QA job and run it, and not to have to approve the Production job. But for some reason, I am not able to run the QA job without approving both QA and Production. So I can run either both jobs or none. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried separating the jobs in different stages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass), approval should be applied to stages. You should have a separate stage with deployment jobs for each environment.

[image]

Try:

```
stages:
- stage: QA
  jobs:
  - deployment: QA
    displayName: QA Deployment
    environment: QA
- stage: Production
  jobs:
  - deployment: Production
    dependsOn: QA
    displayName: Production Deployment
    environment: Production
```